# Inflate a layout with it's theme,height and width

Tags: android

I'm kinda new one in Android Development and I wanna know how can I `inflate` layout but also save width and height and **mainly Theme/style** of layout?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the theme/style in the XML then inflate it, it will take the style/theme:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a template"
        style="@style/my_style" />
```

Then inflate it normally

```
        TextView view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.progress_item, viewGroup, false);
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Can I make it with theme?

Comment: A `Theme` is a group of styles my friend.